# Let's Encrypt with expired CA certificate and Apple Mail

Tags: mail.app, encryption

This week - as my informations - Let's Encrypt CA certificate expires. This has guaranteed correctly managed by R3.
However its two days that I'm fighting with these popup (see below). I renewed my email server certificate yesterday evening.
Anyone can help me understand what's going on?

[image: Apple mail error certificate popup]

Comment: Which version of macOS do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your IMAP server is only serving the leaf certificate, not the intermediate cert(s) that're needed to verify it. You can check this with the `openssl s_client` command:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect imap.piraneo-canepa.ch:imap -starttls imap </dev/null
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=0 CN = piraneo-canepa.ch
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = piraneo-canepa.ch
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=piraneo-canepa.ch
   i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=R3
---
[...]
```

Note that the "Certificate chain" section only lists a single certificate, which is the server's leaf certificate. Compare that with your SMTP (incoming mail) server, which does include the intermediates:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect mail.piraneo-canepa.ch:smtp -starttls smtp </dev/null
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=2 C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=piraneo-canepa.ch
   i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=R3
 1 s:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=R3
   i:/C=US/O=Internet Security Research Group/CN=ISRG Root X1
 2 s:/C=US/O=Internet Security Research Group/CN=ISRG Root X1
   i:/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
---
[...]
```

Here the "Certificate chain" section includes two intermediates along with the server's leaf cert. If you add the `-showcerts` option, it'll print all three certs (in PEM format).

...so I think all you need to do is add those same intermediates to the TLS config on your IMAP server.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems it solved my issue!

My last question: I have to worry about "certificate has expired"?

depth=1 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=Sep 30 14:01:15 2021 GMT
verify return:0
depth=1 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=Sep 30 14:01:15 2021 GMT
verify return:0
depth=3 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=Sep 30 14:01:15 2021 GMT
verify return:0

Comment: @FrancescoPiraneoG. That might or might not be a problem, depending on where you're seeing it. It looks like you're seeing a cross-signature that chains up to the newly-expired root... but as long as it's *also* seeing the chain that goes to a still-valid root, the cert *should* be considered valid because of that chain. If it's just a message, you can ignore it, but if it's causing the cert to be rejected you'll have to figure out why and how to stop it.